# Flutter: Is it possible to use single JSON file in bodies of more expansion panels?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, expansion

In my app, I have one JSON file with some static data which I use to produce List of a widgets. Then, I have one screen with ExpansionPanelRadio showing few items and each of them, when expanded, (in their bodies) are containing that list of a widgets made using JSON file.
I am using provider and I am able to display that list of widgets inside body of expansionpanel but the lists are somehow repeating.

For example, I expand one panel and in its body list is displayed few times, like in a loop. I guess, that the problem is in provider but I don't understand it quite well.

I am pretty new to flutter and would appreciate if someone could explain me why is this happening and what approach should I use to solve it.

here is part of a code where i make those expansion panels with provided JSON in a body:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
        elevation: 0,
        children: MyList.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((Item item) {
          return ExpansionPanelRadio(
              value: MyList.indexOf(item),
              headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assets/images/some_image.svg"
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('some label'),
                  ],
                );
              },
              body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => FeaturesProvider(),
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    Provider.of<FeaturesProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .readFeatures();

                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Features(item.objectId.toString()),
                      ),
                    );
                  }));
        }).toList(),
      ))
```

Comment: Please edit your question & provide your code there.

Comment: okay, I did it.